# Display Based on the parent Term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I need to display widget areas based on the parent term..

Eg:-

Cars
 a. Ford
 b. Porsche
 c. Bmw

Bikes
 a. Honda
 b. Harley
 c. Yamaha

my custom taxonomy is custom_categories

If im on the taxonomy page like something.com?custom_categories=ford or custom_categories=bmw or all child categories of Cars
"then display the widget area A and if"
If im on the taxonomy page something.com?custom_categories=honda  or all child categories of Bikes 
"then display the widget area B "

Eg :-  If parent_tax is cars then do widget 1 else if parent_tax is bikes then do widget2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to get the current term (child taxonomy) of the post you are on, and a parent if it exists:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );
//Return an object $term and parent $term
```

Then look for a specific term by comparing $term->name or seeing if the current term has a parent that matches the name:

```
if($term->name == 'bikes' || $parent->name == 'bikes')):
    // Do widget
else if ($term->name == 'cars' || $parent->name == 'cars')):
    // Do other widget
else:
    // Do default
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to check for the parent taxonomy.. Cos i have multiple terms under cars..Something like.. if parent_tax is cars then do widget 1 .....

Comment: Then simply use `is_tax('cars')` - the first argument is the taxonomy name (cars, motorcycles) and the second argument is the term inside the taxnomoy (cars -> bmw, motorcycles -> ducati).  You don't need the second argument if all you need to do is show a cars widget or a motorcycles widget - but they are there if you want to get very specific with a widget or sidebar.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw the structure of your taxonomy in the question!  Apologies!

Comment: This is what im using if(is_tax( 'custom_categories', 'cars' )).. This works only for cars, but not for the child terms of cars

Comment: Thats ok, but any solution to my question?

Comment: My edit re-approached the problem considering your use of a single custom tax - I haven't done a setup like this, but I believe it will work.

Comment: Thanks Calvin!!! I used the parent id $term->parent and gave the condition!! and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want parents categories for cars. If you have a model of BMW like an M3 you want to show the widget for the parent category of cars or BMW.

You could use the `get_category_parents` function in wordpress. [The function isn't well documented if it returns all parents or just the next parent up.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) So I'm not sure if the function will return just BWM or the full category or cars or both. You might have to nest it in order to go all the way to the top of your categories list.

Regardless once you've got your category returned you can then write an if statement to show a widget or do something.

You'd just do

```
    if ($catParent == 'BWM'){
          //call/show widget 1
           }else if($catParent == 'Ford'){
                   //call widget 2 function
                }else{
                  //Call widget 3 or do something completely different.
                  }
```

Comment: im unable to get the parent taxonmy term using get_category_parents

Comment: How are you writing your function? What error does it return?